# A word for "Progress Bar" when it's not used to measure progress

Tags: computing

What would you call something that looks exactly like a progress bar (ie: When you are installing a program) but that isn't used to measure the progress of a task.

In this case it's used to display the "threat level" of a suspected software, in an anti-virus. But I'm looking for a more general word than "threat bar".

Comment: What about "security alert bar"?

Comment: As Pooja Raja said Alert Bar seems right, and if you want a more generic term try "status bar"

Comment: *Threat gauge* or *Risk indicator*?

Comment: _Threatometer_ or _Threat meter_ are common terms in PC gaming for these sort of bars. _Oh no my threatometer has gone into the red ... bang!_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be describing a ***gauge***.

Answer (score 1):

I've always called it a status bar.

> ### noun
>
> *Computing:*
>
> A horizontal bar, usually at the bottom of the screen or window, showing information about a document being edited or a program running.

While the status bar is often used to describe the bar at the bottom of whatever software you are creating, it doesn't always have to mean that. In your specific case I think a threat status bar would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since in both cases, what the bar is really doing is *indicating* or *displaying* the results of some kind of *measurement*, I would probably call it either a ***measuring bar*** or an ***indicator/display bar*** as a generic hypernym for any such type of bar.

Comment: It's not a *measuring bar* because it doesn't do any measuring, your suggestion of *indicator bar* is much better.  Like the bars in a bar graph.

Comment: The bar itself doesn’t do any measuring, but it does indicate a measure of sorts.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would that make it a "measure bar," then?